# What's the best way to read in an entire LOB using ODBC?

Tags: mysql, odbc, mariadb

Reading in an entire LOB whose size you don't know beforehand (without a max allocation + copy) should be a fairly common problem, but finding good documentation and/or examples on the "right" way to do this has proved utterly maddening for me.

I wrestled with `SQLBindCol` but couldn't see any good way to make it work.  `SQLDescribeCol` and `SQLColAttribute` return column metadata that seemed to be a default or an upper bound on the column size and not the current LOB's actual size.  In the end, I settled on using the following:

1) Put any / all LOB columns as the highest numbered columns in your SELECT statement

2) `SQLPrepare` the statement

3) `SQLBindCol` any earlier non-LOB columns that you want

4) `SQLExecute` the statement

5) `SQLFetch` a result row

6) `SQLGetData` on your LOB column with a buffer of size 0 just to query its actual size

7) Allocate a buffer just big enough to hold your LOB

8) `SQLGetData` again on your LOB column with your correctly sized allocated buffer this time

9) Repeat Steps 6-8 for each later LOB column

10) Repeat Steps 5-9 for any more rows in your result set

11) `SQLCloseCursor` when you are done with your result set

This seems to work for me, but also seems rather involved.

Are the calls to SQLGetData going back to the server or just processing the results already sent to the client?

Are there any gotchas where the server and/or client will refuse to process very large objects this way (e.g. - some size threshold is exceeded so they generate an error instead)?

Most importantly, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see several improvements to be done.

1. If you need to allocate a buffer then you should do it once for all the records and columns. So, you could use the technique suggested by @RickJames, improved with a `MAX` like this:

   SELECT MAX(LENGTH(blob1)) AS max1, MAX(LENGTH(blob2)) AS max2, ...

You could use `max1` and `max2` to upfront allocate the buffers, or maybe only the largest one for all columns.

2. The length of the buffer returned at 1. might be too large for your application. You could decide at runtime how large the buffer would be. Anyway, `SQLGetData` is designed to be called multiple times for each column. Just by calling it again, with the same column number, it will fetch the next chunk. The count of available bytes will be saved where `StrLen_or_IndPtr` (the last argument) points. And this count will decrease after each call with the amount of bytes fetched.

And certainly there will be roundtrips to the server for each call because the purpose of all this is to prevent the driver from fetching more than the application can handle.

3. The trick with passing `NULL` as buffer pointer in order to get the length is prohibited in this case, check [SQLGetData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/fetching-a-row-of-data?view=sql-server-2017) on Microsoft's Docs.

However, you could allocate a minimal buffer, say 8 bytes, pass it and its length. The function will return the count of bytes written, 7 in our case because the function add a null char, and will put at `StrLen_or_IndPtr` the count of remaining bytes.  But you probably won't need this if you allocate the buffer as explained above.

Note: The LOBs need to be at the end of the select list **and** must be fetched in that order precisely.

Comment: I just re-read `SQLGetData`'s MS documentation and you are correct that they declare the buffer pointer cannot be NULL.  Yet, they also say, "The driver uses BufferLength to avoid writing past the end of the *TargetValuePtr buffer when returning variable-length data, such as character or binary data."  So, I'll update my code to pass a random non-NULL pointer to nothing with a `BufferLength` of zero in case a particular driver is too pedantic for its own good or use your small buffer suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## SQLGetData

`SQLGetData` get the result of already fetched result. For example, if you have `SQLFetch` the first row of your table, `SQLData` will send you back the first row. It is used if you don't know if you can `SQLBindCol` the result.

But the way it is handle depends on your driver and is not describe in the standards. If your database is a SQL database, cursor cannot go backward, so the result may be still in the memory.

## Large object query

The server may refuse to process large object according to the **server  standard** and your **ODBC Driver** standard. It is not described in the **ODBC standard**.

Comment: Do you agree that the best way to do this is to first query the size of the LOB using `SQLGetData(..., NULL, 0, ...)` and then calling `SQLGetData` again with a properly sized allocated buffer?  Typically, does that cause multiple round trips back and forth to the server or not?

Comment: @jschultz410 I can't affirm it's the best way. But it seems to be as far as I know. Particularly in the case of `SQLGetData` doesn't make any query to the server and doesn't copy anything into a `NULL` buffer.

Comment: A good way to verify that `SQLGetData` doesn't interact with the server is to `wire-shark` it.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a max-allocation, doing an extra copy, and to be efficient:

Getting the size first is not a bad approach -- it takes virtually no extra time to do

```
SELECT LENGTH(your_blob) FROM ...
```

Then do the allocation and actually fetch the blob.

If there are multiple BLOB columns, grab all the lengths in a single pass:

```
SELECT LENGTH(blob1), LENGTH(blob2), ... FROM ...
```

In MySQL, the length of a `BLOB` or `TEXT` is readily available in front of the bytes.  But, even if it must read the column to get the length, think of that as merely priming the cache.  That is, the overall time is not hurt much in either case.